# How do I center a list of DIVs horizontally?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Imagin each of the dots below is a div, How do I achieve this?
I need to float then left, for them to be in the same line, but them they are aligned to the left.

```
                        *
                      * * * 
                    * * * * *
```

Comment: You want that layout with floats? No absolute positioning?

Comment: @alex - I do not know in advance the actual number of items, I probably can calculate it on the spot, but I prefer a more generic solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`display: inline-block`](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) is perfect for this. That on the children, combined with `text-align: center` on the containing `div` is all you need.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/S4aFj/2/